# Какая должна быть грамматика для распознавания речи?

Tags: c#, wpf, распознавание-речи

Моя программа должна распознавать речь, я использую SpeechRecognitionEngine, но для его работы нужны Grammar и GrammarBuilder, вот я не могу разобраться какая должна быть грамматика для полного распознавания речи а не отдельных фраз

Comment: [`GrammarBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.grammarbuilder?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Grammar builder нужен для построения грамматики, я задал вопрос, чтобы узнать какую грамматику нужно построить, чтобы SRE распознавал всю речь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там есть для распознавания произвольной речи [DictationGrammar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Да увидел, но все равно спасибо) Только дело теперь в том , что текст который распознается отличается от того, что говорил пользователь